# why jQuery show() is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using **jQuery** to hide a div via `hide()`.

Then when a link is clicked it will show the `div`, but for some reason it will not stay.
it will show for a ms then disappear.

**HTML**

```
<div id="introContent">
    <h1 id="introText">Welcome</h1>
    <p id="introParagraph">I create <strong>Responsive</strong>, <strong>Interactive</strong>, <strong>Beautiful</strong> Mobile ready Websites.
        Every Website is created from scratch for each client so no Two Projects are alike.
        Please read more about my Company and our work.
        "High Quality Work at Affordable Prices"
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#introContent").hide();
    $("#intro").click(function () { //$(#intro) is a link in my nav bar 
        $("#introContent").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: what is `intro` exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stop the browser from doing the default action of the element you are clicking. Cancel the click

```
$(function() {
    $("#introContent").hide();
    $("#intro").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#introContent").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I blanked about the default action.
Would you know how to hide it again on another click?

Comment: Make sure to mark your questions as solved by picking the answer that answers your question.